# Error saving QML item as image to file, using grabToImage

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a QML item that I'm trying to [grab as an image](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method). With QML like so…

```
Item {
    id: content
    ...
}

FileDialog {
    folder: shortcuts.documents
    selectExisting: false
    onAccepted: {
        content.grabToImage(function(result){
            if (!result.saveToFile(fileUrl)){
              console.error('Unknown error');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

…I always get the "Unknown error" text, even when I enter a file name like "Test.png".

What's wrong? How can I save my file to an image?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `url` supplied by the `FileDialog` is not valid as an argument to `saveToFile`.

Although the [`saveToFile` method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-itemgrabresult.html#saveToFile-method) does not document the required type of the argument, [the source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitemgrabresult.cpp#n184) shows that it expects a `QString`.

This is not enough, however. You must also remove the protocol from the file URL for this to work. For example, while `fileUrl.toString()` may result in
`"file:///Users/phrogz/Document/Test.png"`
the `saveToFile` method requires a string like
`"/Users/phrogz/Document/Test.png"`

Thus:

```
FileDialog {
    folder: shortcuts.documents
    selectExisting: false
    onAccepted: {
        var urlNoProtocol = (fileUrl+"").replace('file://', '');
        content.grabToImage(function(result){
            if (!result.saveToFile(urlNoProtocol)){
              console.error('Unknown error saving to',urlNoProtocol);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have opened [Qt bug #44450](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44450) to track this issue. Clearly the URL should be accepted directly by `saveToFile`.

Comment: Wow, digia usually doesn't fix bugs for years, but they fixed yours a full year before you found it :D

Comment: @ddriver Hah. Oops. I meant [bug #56436](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56436).